# Expressing coefficients of a differential equation as decimal numbers

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I have a differential equation as such:
$$\frac{d^2i}{dt^2}+7\frac{di}{dt}+12i(t)=36\delta(t-2)
$$
Where $i(0)=0, i'(0)=0$. The solution is given by:
$$i(t)=u(t-2)[Ae^{-3(t-2)}+Be^{-4(t-2)}]
$$
Out of the solution, I need to express $A$ and $B$ as decimal numbers. Now, I can solve simpler differential equations, but the $\delta$ is completely throwing me off.

Comment: Is $i(t)$ current or something?

Comment: @JanEerland I believe this example will lead to a question where i(t) is current.

Comment: I found that $\text{A}=36$ and $\text{B}=-36$

Comment: @JanEerland Great, thank you! Would you be able to share the steps, if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $$i_0=Ae^{−3(t−2)}+Be^{−4(t−2)}$$ you need $i_0(2)=0$ and $i_0'(2)=36$ so that $$i(t)=u(t-2)i_0(t)$$ has the correct kink generating $36δ(t−2)$ in the second derivative. This gives the linear equations
$$
A+B=0\\
-3A-4B=36
$$
which gives $A=-B=36$ as the solution.